# Multiple Print buttons on one HTML page, only printing certain sections?

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I am in the process of creating a page that has multiple tiles, with each tile having it's own print button.  Once the print button is clicked I only want to display the contents in that tile to be printed.

I'm using @media print display:none any contents that are not in the tiles (which works), but the issue I'm having is each tile displays when a print button is selected.

Is it possible to use multiple @media prints or isolate them?  If not, how do indicate in @media print to only include one tile, based on which one is clicked to print?  Below ends up printing all tiles.

Example:

```
    @media print
    {
    .noprint {display:none;}
    }

   <div class="noprint">
      OTHER STUFF
   </div>

   <div class="printcard1" id=BM">
      <a href="javascript:window.print()">PrintMe!</a>
      -CONTENT-
   </div>

   <div class="printcard2" id=KM">
      <a href="javascript:window.print()">PrintMe!</a>
      -CONTENT-
   </div>
```

etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find a solution for multiple print buttons on the same page.  Wanted to share in case someone else was in the search as well.

```
<script>
    function printDiv1() {
        var divContents = document.getElementById("Tile1").innerHTML;
        var a = window.open('', '', 'height=500, width=500');
        a.document.write('<html>');
        a.document.write('<body>');
        a.document.write(divContents);
        a.document.write('</body></html>');
        a.document.close();
        a.print();
    }

    function printDiv2() {
        var divContents = document.getElementById("Tile2").innerHTML;
        var a = window.open('', '', 'height=500, width=500');
        a.document.write('<html>');
        a.document.write('<body>');
        a.document.write(divContents);
        a.document.write('</body></html>');
        a.document.close();
        a.print();
    }  

</script>



<div class="PrintRec1" id="Tile1">
  CONTENTS
    <input type="button" value="Print this Recipe" onclick="printDiv1()">
</div>

<div class="PrintRec2" id="Tile2">
  CONTENTS
    <input type="button" value="Print this Recipe" onclick="printDiv2()">
</div>
```